# Postgres count total matches per group

Tags: postgresql

## Input data

I have the following association table:

```
AssociationTable
 - Item ID: Integer
 - Tag ID: Integer
```

Referring to the following example data

```
Item  Tag
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
```

and some input list of tags T (e.g. `[1, 2]`)

## What I want

For each item, I would like to know which tags were not provided in the input list T.

With our sample data, we'd get:

```
Item   Num missing
1      1
2      0
```

## My thoughts

The best I've done so far is: `select "ItemId", count("TagId") as "Num missing" from "AssociationTab" where "TagId" not in (1) group by "ItemId";`

The problem here is that items where all tags match will not be included in the output.

Comment: I fail to see how the output you show is what you describe as the desired output.  Item 1 has tags 1,2 and 3 (none missing from list) and item 2 has tag 1.  Tag 2 missing for list.  Please explain.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I'm passing [1, 2], so item 1 is missing tag 3 and item 2 is not missing any since tag 1 is in the input list

Comment: I see.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is

```sql
SELECT
    ItemId,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE TagId NOT IN (1,2))
FROM AssociationTab
GROUP BY ItemId
```

Alternatively, if you already have an `Items` table with the item list, you could do this:

```sql
SELECT
    i.ItemId,
    count(a.TagId)
FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN AssociationTab a ON a.ItemId = i.ItemId AND a.TagId NOT IN (1,2)
GROUP BY i.ItemId
```

The key is that LEFT JOIN does not remove the `Items` row if no tags match.

Comment: I love the first one! I wasn't aware of FILTER... this is great!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a calendar table with anti-join approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.Item, t2.Tag
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM AssociationTable) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS Tag UNION ALL SELECT 2) t2
)

SELECT
    t1.Item,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t2.Item IS NULL) AS num_missing
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN AssociationTable t2
    ON t1.Item = t2.Item AND
       t1.Tag = t2.Tag AND
       t2.Tag IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
    t1.Item;
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to build a calendar/reference table in the first CTE which contains all combinations of items and tags.  Then, we left join this CTE to your association table, aggregate by item, and then detect how many tags are missing for each item.